# Algorithm for creating a large number of points in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, points

I am trying to design an algorithm that creates random points in a square.

The problem is: if we have a mxm square, we randomly create n points with 1 < n < m²

The algorithm has to be efficient, that means if m = 500, we can have either n = 1000 or n = 100 000. And the cost of the algorithm must be the same. So m should not be a factor of the cost.

I really don't know what to do...
I frist though about doing this:

```
for (int n = 1000, n > 0, n--) {
create a point
}
```

But this way m is a factor of the cost...

Do you know any algorithm that could help?

Thank you

Matt

Comment: Homework? Unless there is a company that is desperate to see some random points in a square...

Comment: @Stargazer most likely, but it is frowned upon to use the homework tag

Comment: @Woot4Moo, since when? Adding a homework tag is the most common edit made to tags.

Comment: check out this link, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions  Admit that the question is homework. Trying to hide it will just get the question closed faster. Do this by mentioning that it is homework in the question text; the homework tag, like other so-called "meta" tags, is now discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements sounds impossible to me.

You say that you need to create `n` points, where `n` will be any number from `1` to `m^2`.

It should be clear that if `m` grows, the probability of getting a higher `n` increases.  So, as `m` grows, the number of points (`n`) you will create must grow.

Creating a point is constant time, and independent of any other points created.  So, as `n` grows, so will the work required to generate `n` points.

Using Big Oh though, the following algorithm will take `O(m^2)` time to create `n` points:

```
Random r = new Random();
int m; // something
int n = r.nextInt(m*m-1) + 1; // random number between 1 and m^2
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) { 
    // create a random point in the square 
    Point p = new Point(r.nextInt(m), r.nextInt(m));
}
```

Comment: @Mark, that is still `O(m^2)`.  But, a bit more complex algorithm.

Comment: The thing is that I have to check that we don't have 2 points at the same spot. Isn't that going to increase the cost?

Comment: I initially thought that as well, however `m` is the bound and there is no need to pass over `m` repeatedly so I think it would fall to `O(n)`

Comment: @Woot, well if `n` is randomly chosen to be `m^2` then it is `O(m^2)`.

Comment: Worst case scenario for n unique points is `List<Point> listOfAllPoints; Collections.shuffle(listOfAllPoints); return new ArrayList<Point>(listOfAllPoints.subList(0, N));`  So yes definitely still possible in `O(m^2)`

Comment: OK but the thing is that we have to check if 2 points have the same x and y coordinates at the end of the for loop. This won't be very efficient...

Comment: @Matt, Look at @Mark Peters comment for the basic idea to get unique points.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that the algorithm will always be `O(n)` as a worst case.  The assumption here is that your professor is using the definition of Big-O being the worst case, not the best or average case performance.  Therefore I do believe that `m` is always what will be the factor, regardless of what it is.

Comment: Why `n^2` and not just `O(n)`?

Comment: You are right, its only a single pass of the entire set.  My mistake

Comment: @Mark, it is `O(n)` where `n = m^2`

Comment: @jjnguy you always use worst case scenario